# google play does not filter as per manifest configuration

Tags: android, android-screen-support

My application is on goole play and manifest configuration is like

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
 <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

But after uploading it shows

```
API level: 4-16+
Supported screens: small-xlarge
OpenGL textures: all
```

How it works??..why small-xlarge??..My xlarge is false already.

Can I missing something???

Help me!! Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure, but it might due to the fact that xlargeScreens was introduced in API level 9.

Comment: You means if my android:minSdkVersion="9" then it will works?????

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but you can try setting targetSdkVersion to at least 9 and see if it changes anything. maybe minSdk although affects it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in Product Details Tab . There is one field Support Device, There you can find the exact description for that .

Please check this [link](http://www.jdamcd.com/?p=877) .

Comment: in that is it shows all Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE ?

Comment: Yes   it's look like

Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features
android.hardware.camera
android.hardware.screen.landscape
android.hardware.screen.portrait
android.hardware.touchscreen

Comment: I trid with your answer..and it works...please help for only tablet devices.